# Maintain single DB connection for multiple cron jobs

Tags: php, mysql, cron, connection-pooling

Is it possible to maintain single DB connection or object for separate cron jobs. Script is written in PHP.

I have multiple independent cron jobs running to insert/update DB. That also every 15 mins running. Recently max db connection exceeded.

Is there any service to maintain db connection? like using node.js or javascript 
Or is it possible connection-pooling using php?

I tried persistent connection using PHP like this,

```
$link = mysqli_connect('p:localhost', 'fake_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

But then not working as expected. Each cron job generate separate connection to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

There is no connection pooling feature in PHP but some short you can achieve it by using "mysql_pconnect". At the same time, you have to be very careful while using mysql_pconnect.

According to PHP mysql_pconnect:

mysql_pconnect() acts very much like mysql_connect() with two major differences.

First, when connecting, the function would first try to find a (persistent) link that's already open with the same host, username, and password. If one is found, an identifier for it will be returned instead of opening a new connection.

Second, the connection to the SQL server will not be closed when the execution of the script ends. Instead, the link will remain open for future use (mysql_close() will not close links established by mysql_pconnect()).

This type of link is therefore called 'persistent'.

More info click [here](http://ir.php.net/function.mysql-pconnect)

You can do one more thing that you have to close all DB connection which is ideal for more than 30 sec or 1 minute and this can be done through cron itself.

Secondly, you have to open a single connection in your cron script and have to close it at the end after execution of the script.